# Is it necessary for webpack to converting the code to AST, if the browser support all the syntax about javascript and css,

Tags: javascript, webpack, abstract-syntax-tree

Recently I have learned the process of `webpack` bundling are as follows:

1. read the config file and register the hooks
2. get the module file
   (processed by the loaders) and convert the code to AST
3. convert the
   AST to the code that browser could  understand, outout the chunk
   file to the dist

I have miss some process, but My question is that step two.
if the browser support all the syntax of javascript and css（like import）, is necessary for webpack to convert the code to AST.

Comment: My premise is that all browsers can recognize the code written. After all, it's a repeat ingress to turn code into AST and then into recognizable code, and then the browser turns the code into AST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) is simply a data structure used by any software to understand code. It's a significantly better mechanism for parsing code as compared to using something like string manipulation.

Webpack needs to use ASTs to understand and process your code. Without this, Webpack won't be able to figure out the list of dependencies to pack together, or if there is any dead code that needs to be eliminated, or if there is any code that needs to be transpiled from ES6 to ES5, etc.

Similarly, browsers convert your code to ASTs so that they can understand the instructions and execute them.